# OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY in 2019 compatible 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have a script like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MYTABLE]
(
    ....
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MYTABLE] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Legend_Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

On SQL Server 2017, it does not run (`OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` is not a recognized `CREATE TABLE` option)

On SQL Server 2019 (with the database in SQL Server 2017 compatibility mode), it runs successfully.

[image]

We are using SQL Server 2019 to validate something that will be executed on SQL Server 2017. I think this is weird and I was expecting a failure also in the SQL Server 2019 version.

Is there a way to force SQL Server 2019 to strictly behave as SQL Server 2017?

Comment: Compatibility level != emulate version. If you want to test something works on a 2017 instance, run it on a 2017 instance.

Comment: Where did your script come from? Most tools allow you to set a target compatability level, including SSMS

Comment: This statements cames from a dev using 2019 (and not 2017 as company policy). But my work is to write automation to check SQL files and I was using a 2019 server in compatibility mode 2017... and I was not able to identify the problem

Comment: If you just need to parse scripts to verify version compatibility, you can use a [T-SQL Script DOM parser](https://www.dbdelta.com/2020/06/07/microsoft-sql-server-script-dom/) even without a database engine.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful to you - your script *looks* to be that which would be generated by SSMS.

In the options, if you go to `SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting` there is a *Version Options* section:

[image]

Comment: This is a good advice for the dev who created that file. I'm in charge of automation checking sql 2017 validitity. I'm using 2019 compatible 2017 and I understood that this is a mistake

Comment: @Riccardo79 - and you're doing a fine job. Reject the file that came from the dev saying that it failed the check and pass along the above advice for a way for them to provide a file that passes the check.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force SQL Server 2019 to strictly behave as SQL Server 2017?

Compatibility mode is there to facilitate upgrades by preventing breaking changes and optimizer enhancements when running a workload tested on an older version and running on a newer version.

But just because your application is running in compatibility mode doesn't mean you can't start using new features introduced in SQL Server 2019.  Some changes may be blocked to protect backwards-compatibility, but most will be available to use if you want.